# Loading elements of an ASP.NET page with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a page that has content in 4 jQuery tabs. I want to detect which tab is being accessed and load that content with AJAX, so that the page is presented to the user in a more timely manner.

Reading about ASP.NET AJAX, I've come across UpdatePanels, but it seems to be used for updating certain elements with reloading the entire page on postbacks. Can they be used to load content on the initial page load? Would I wrap the content of each tab with an UpdatePanel and somehow use JavaScript to begin loading the content after the non-AJAX elements load?

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I feel like I am so lost.

Comment: jQuery Tabs support AJAX natively (http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax) just use this feature to bring in external content

Comment: So would I copy the content of each tab and move it into its own .aspx page? And then link to that page?